# What's the right way to wait for Thread::Queue to finish?

Tags: perl, loops

I'm trying to build a simple crawler, but it seems all threads never finishes, even the queue is empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my %visited = ();
my $workQueue = new Thread::Queue;

sub work {
    my ($ua, $queue, $hashref) = @_;
    my $tid = threads->self->tid;
    my $linkExtor = new HTML::LinkExtor;

    while (my $next = $queue->dequeue)
    {
        print "Processin ($tid): ", $next, "\n";

        my $resp = $ua->get ($next);
        if ($resp->is_success)
        {
            $linkExtor->parse ($resp->content);
            my @links = map { my($tag, %attrs) = @$_; 
            ($tag eq 'a')
            ? $attrs{href} : () } $linkExtor->links;

            $queue->enqueue (@links);
        }
    }
};

$workQueue->enqueue ('http://localhost');
my @threads = map { threads->create (\&work, $ua, $workQueue, \%visited) } 1..10;
$_->join for @threads;
```

So what's the right way to wait for those threads to finish? It never jump out of that while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$queue->dequeue` is blocking and waiting for another thread to `enqueue` something. From the [perldoc](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread%3a%3aQueue):

> Removes the requested number of items (default is 1) from the head of the queue, and returns them. If the queue contains fewer than the requested number of items, then the thread will be blocked until the requisite number of items are available **(i.e., until other threads <enqueue> more items)**.

`dequeue_nb()` will return undef if the queue is empty. But in this case, if one thread has dequeued the first URL, the rest will have stopped before any items are queued.

Off the top off my head, an alternative approach might be to keep a count of threads that are currently engaged in some activity and terminate when that hits 0?

Answer (score 1):

[Thread::Queue 3.01](https://metacpan.org/module/JDHEDDEN/Thread-Queue-3.01/lib/Thread/Queue.pm) just introduced a [solution to this problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=79733).  You can now declare that a queue has ended indicating that no more items will be added to the queue.  This unblocks anyone waiting on `dequeue` and `dequeue` will not block when the queue is empty allowing your threads to exit.

```
$workQueue->enqueue('http://localhost');
my @threads = map { threads->create (\&work, $ua, $workQueue, \%visited) } 1..10;
$workQueue->end;
$_->join for @threads;
```

Unfortunately for you, ending a queue also means that you can no longer add items to the queue, so a thread in the middle of spidering a web page cannot add the pages it finds to the queue.  I wrote the original Thread::Queue patch which did not have this restriction.  There's no technical reason why an ended queue could not take more items, the restriction is a design choice by the Thread::Queue author.  You might want to [give him some feedback](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=Thread-Queue) and let him know it's getting in the way.

Here is [my original patch](https://github.com/schwern/Thread-Queue) which defines `done` instead of `end` and allows you to continue to add items to a `done` queue.